# "read.table" converts every '+' in a column names to '.'

Tags: r

I'm reading a text file in R, using "read.table" function.
The text file actually is a table with columns name. When I try to read this text file, the "read.table" converts every '+' in columns name to '.'. For example if in the text file the name of a column is: "CD34+", after reading it with "read.table", it is converted to: "CD34.".
I tried to set stringAsFactors to FALSE, but it did not work.

Does anyone have an idea what is the solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use the option `check.names=FALSE`.

```
read.table(header=TRUE, check.names=FALSE, text="a+b c+d
0 1")
##   a+b c+d
## 1   0   1
```

Using this option allows syntactically-invalid names.